# Which phrase is grammaticaly correct?

Tags: grammaticality

1. Why is being an adult so tiring?
2. Why being an adult is so tiring?

Many thanks for kind assistance!)

Answer (score 1):

Only the first sentence is grammatically correct because this is an interrogative sentence. The order of words in 'Wh-questions' must be inverted, i.e., there is an auxiliary or modal verb after the interrogative word, for example: 'Who did you see yesterday? / What must we do at the moment? / Where are you going?, etc.

Comment: I see. But does the second (grammatically incorrect) version have the same sense as the first one for native english speakers?  Do they understand meaning of the sentences in both cases equally?

Comment: The second sentence can be understood properly even when it is grammatically wrong. By the way, the order of words   in the second sentence would be  correct if you used it in an embedded question, for example: Can you explain me why being an adult is so tiring?

Answer (score 0):

The *first* version has proper word order for a simple question. The alternative word order is for reported speech (embedded question):

> He told me why being an adult is so tiring.

or

> Can you tell me why being an adult is so tiring?

https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/embedded-questions.html